# SQL: Select Foreign Records Using Complex Join

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I want to select a "site" record(s) randomly, and then get the related "channels" for it. Here's what I've tried that doesn't work. Please help. Thank you!

```
    SELECT A.*, B.*
    FROM (
        SELECT companies.company_name, sites.id
        FROM sites
        INNER JOIN company_sites ON company_sites.site_id = sites.id
        INNER JOIN companies ON companies.id = company_sites.company_id
        WHERE sites.active = 1
        AND sites.stage_id = 5
        GROUP BY sites.id
        ORDER BY RAND()
        LIMIT 1
    )A
    JOIN ( 
        SELECT 
        channels.id
        FROM channels 
        WHERE channels.site_id = A.sites_id
    ) B ON 1 = 1
```

Comment: What the condition `ON 1 = 1` is for? Do you realize it produces a cartesian product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT just the fields you need
FROM (
    SELECT companies.company_name, sites.id id
    FROM sites
    INNER JOIN company_sites ON company_sites.site_id = sites.id
    INNER JOIN companies ON companies.id = company_sites.company_id
    WHERE sites.active = 1
    AND sites.stage_id = 5
    GROUP BY sites.id
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 1
)A
join channels on channels.site_id = id
```

Comment: it looks like this may be working, but I need to add back some criterion and joins  'code' SELECT A.site_id, channels.id AS channels_id
FROM (
    SELECT sites.id AS site_id
    FROM sites
    WHERE sites.active = 1
    AND sites.stage_id = 5
    GROUP BY sites.id
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 1
)A
LEFT JOIN channels on channels.site_id = A.site_id

Comment: Why would you do a left join instead of an inner join?  Do you have any sites without any channels?

Comment: ok, i added back my criteria and this worked well. thank you! i am impressed with this community once again.

Comment: one more thing please, how can I add a line to COUNT the distinct site.id that are being returned so I can verify the LIMIT is working for the business people?

Comment: I suggest that you prove the limit works by running a separate query when challenged.

Answer (score 1):

By the way, if you just wanted the list of channels on each site, you can concatenate them into one field (rather than getting them on separate rows).  The query would be simpler:

```
    SELECT companies.company_name, sites.id, group_concat(channels.id) as channels
    FROM sites
    INNER JOIN company_sites ON company_sites.site_id = sites.id
    INNER JOIN companies ON companies.id = company_sites.company_id
    inner join channels on channels.site_id = sites.id
    WHERE sites.active = 1
    AND sites.stage_id = 5
    GROUP BY sites.id
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This is what I was going to reply to. I don't think you need the `LIMIT 1` though. OP had that in the subquery

Comment: @Hayden . . . The question explicitly says to get "a site record".  I think the OP only wants one.

Comment: Good enough. The original question says that but the original query made it appear it was only limiting within the subquery.